# Split function increase new space character after splitting the string

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist

I am facing a problem in split function in java. I am reading list of strings from a file and storing them into two arraylists. Each string contains a letter + whitespace +number. I used the split function to get letters in one of the arraylist and numbers in the other arraylist. 
The numbers arraylist adds numbers correctly, but the letters arraylist adds a letter followed by whitespace, but I don't know why ?!

Here is the file :

```
a 1
b 01
c 001
d 000
```

the code :

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("ListOfCodes.txt.txt"));
String output="";   
ArrayList<String> Codes =  new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String>Letters = new ArrayList<String>();
String []separated ;
    while(s.hasNextLine())
    {
        output=s.nextLine();
           separated = output.split(" ");
          for(int k=0;k<separated.length;k++ )
          {   
              if(k==0)
             Letters.add(separated[k]);
              if(k==1)
              Codes.add(separated[k]);

          }
          output="";
    }
      output="";




      for(int i=0;i<Letters.size();i++)
        System.out.println(Letters.get(i));

      for(int i=0;i<Codes.size();i++)
          System.out.println(Codes.get(i));
```

Output for Codes arraylist :

```
1
01
001
000
```

Output for Letters arraylist :

```
a

b

c

d
```

Comment: Is it possible that there are new line characters before or after space like `\r` or `\n`? If so maybe try with `split("\\s+")`?

Comment: I've tried it but it didn't work :/

Comment: Then I can't reproduce your problem. I suspect that either code you are using is different or format of input file not as you show us.

Answer (score 2):

There may be trailing spaces in your file. So better use `trim` method before storing them in the list.

Comment: trailing space or `\r` `\n` symbols

Comment: Yes, based on his edit it's clear that he's getting the endline character in there. Trim will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using split like this:

```
separated = output.split("\\s+"); // \\s matches white spaces including newlines as well
```

This will give you array of string with striped new lines in the end.